# How to send key commands to another PC in .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, sendkeys

I see a lot of examples where key strokes/commands are sent to other applications on the same PC, but I need to send key stroke commands to another PC. Is this possible? Through remote desktop or cleaner/easier way?

The goal here is that I press a key here, I need to execute that key (say it opens a program) on another PC without the need for a program installed on the client. Think about sending CTR + ALT + DEL on another PC.

Edit: we have Kinect plugged in to one of us PC's (which we intend to use as Server) and then we have many clients who will be receiving these key commands. Imagine I tell Kinect to open PowerPoint for me on some PC, since PowerPoint can be opened with a key command, I was hoping the easiest way would be to send those key commands from my Server. If this is not possible, then what are the alternative ways to do it? I am trying to avoid any application deployed on the clients, else I believe RDP could work then?

Comment: Please clarify your restrictions (since on one hand you talk about remote desktop and on other hand "without need for a program...") and possibly add your actual goal as it likely can be achieved in much more standard ways. Side note: I don't think you can send Ctrl+Alt+Del on local PC...

Answer (score 1):

> without the need for a program installed on the client

There has to be a server on the target PC to receive your commands. Since you exclude installing a program, this leaves us with the OS (I assume Windows), and afaik remote desktop.

The link below might help with this purpose (I haven't used it myself):
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43705/Remote-Desktop-using-C-NET

Comment: So Windows or .Net does not have some kind of way to send a keystroke to some PC (using IP or something)? Our goal here is to avoid two way communication... just one way.

Comment: Sure it does, but there needs to be a server (listener) at the other side. So I doubt Kinect can be your server; the server must be a program/OS service on the target PC. It will still be one-way communication but it needs an endpoint.

Comment: I see. I figured out a way to use my Kinect PC as the Server and every client needs my client program installed, all of them received the Kinect signals (video and such), but I was hoping we could do something similar without having to install that client software. I just wanted to trigger some keys on another PC.

Comment: I understand. Unfortunately I don't know a way to accomplish what you'd like to, it doesn't seem possible to me.

Answer (score 0):

you must use a network comminication like a tcp or udp and you can use [SendKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). but there is no way to listen commands without running an application at remote pc.